# Monix Coeval.memoize blows the stack

Tags: scala, monix

Define

```
def memoizeCoeval(n: Int): Coeval[Int] = {
  if (n <= 1)
    Coeval.now(1)
  else
    Coeval.defer(memoizeCoeval(n - 1)).map(_ + 1).memoize
}
```

Now

```
memoizeCoeval(10000).value
```

blows the stack. If we remove the `.memoize` from the recursive call, it works (as expected). Why?

Answer (score 0):

It is shortcoming of Coeval, you may use Eval instead of it for stack-safe recursive memoized computations in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

Without `memoize`, you get a Coeval which is a composition of `Suspend`s. Each `Suspend` contains a thunk that is a function that returns the next `Suspend`: the run loop unrolls that by calling `apply` on the thunk, setting the resulting `Coeval` as the current one, and then continuing the loop.

When using `memoize`, the `Suspend` contains a `LazyVal` which extends `() -> Coveal`. It overrides `apply` in a way that calls directly `apply` on its own underlying thunk, which in turn calls the run loop. So when `LazyVal`’s `apply` is called in the run loop, it calls the run loop recursively, which causes the stack overflow.

I don’t know if it’s a bug as `Coeval` is meant to be stack safe, but note that it doesn’t make sense to memoize each step of your recursive method as the corresponding Coveal will never be reused. You probably want to memoize only the final result.